# EF Code first Eager loading problem

Tags: ef-code-first, eager-loading

I have two entities in 1:n relationship: Category and Product.

```
public class Category 
{
   public int CategoryID { get; set; }
   public string CategoryName { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
   public int ProductID { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }

  public virtual Product { get; set; }
}

public class context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

I want to load products in every category by Eager loading.

```
context.Categories.Include(c=>c.Products)
```

but Include do not load any navigation property. it accept only one parameter called "path" typed string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you missing a using? VS 2010 is a bit dumb on this one and you often have to explicitly put in:

```
using System.Data.Entity
```

..to get the lambda include option available.

It won't prompt you to add it as it already has a string based definition for Include available under

```
System.Linq
```

.Include(x => x.MyObject) is actually a new extension method for the existing linq method.

Comment: I can't upvote this enough as it seems this isn't well known.  I thought the only way to eager load was using strings, and strings were causing issues with things not properly eager loading

Comment: Thanks! I agree. Seems a bit of a let down to go to all that trouble to have everything strongly typed then reference it with a string (ie Bring on the runtime errors) :)